# differential equations solution team

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

> Find the general solution set:
> $$(x^2-y^2+1)dx+(x^2-y^2-1)dy=0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question. Can you share your attempts, confusion, issues? Thanks.

Comment: ok sir. thx for link.

Comment: What does that title mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I take it to mean that he wants to assemble a team of people to do his homework for him.

Comment: I couldn't solve the question I shared here so they can help. Where did you get your homework? Would it be bad if you helped, even with homework?

Comment: You just replicated the task, you did not really ask a question. What do you know about such tasks, how far did you get with your previous attempts, what patterns do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an example of a first-order nonlinear ODE. As you state in your question, you are not looking for a hint nor a step-by-step solution, but for a general solution.

General solution:

$ e^{\frac{1}{2}(y(x)+x)^2} (x-y(x)) = c1 $

Comment: thank you. Can you explain how you made the solution?